# initialize and apply structure-parameters using function pointers as structure members

Tags: c, oop, function-pointers

In the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int (*func1)();
    int (*func2)();
}STR_X2;
void init(STR_X2 self , int _a , int _b){
    self.a = _a;
    self.b = _b;
    printf("Init a:%d, b:%d \n",self.a,self.b);
}
int multiply(STR_X2 self){
    printf("Multiply a:%d, b:%d, res:%d\n",self.a,self.b,self.a*self.b);
    return self.a*self.b;
}

int main(void) {
    static STR_X2 val2;
    val2.func1 = init;
    val2.func2 = multiply;

    printf("set values of a and b using init() function\n");
    val2.func1(val2,3,5);
    printf("result:%d\n",val2.func2(val2));

    printf("\nset values of a and b directly\n");
    val2.a=3;
    val2.b = 5;
    printf("result:%d\n",val2.func2(val2));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the structure `STR_X2` has two members as function pointers.

- `func1` is set as `init()` and ses values of the Parameters `a` and `b`.
- `func2` is set as `multiply()` and multiplies the `a` and `b`

By running the code, I have the following result:

```
set values of a and b using init() function
Init a:3, b:5 
Multiply a:0, b:0, res:0
result:0

set values of a and b directly
Multiply a:3, b:5, res:15
result:15
```

which means initializing the parameters using `func1()` does not work. 
 Could anybody help me to find what's wrong with this code?
Thanks

Comment: You need to use `STR_X2*` as function parameter or none of this code makes the slightest sense.

Comment: Btw your code horribly violates the most basic rule of OOP, namely private encapsulation.

Comment: By using `int (*func)()` without arguments (i.e. `int (*multiply)(int, int)`), your code is less safe. I would also consider initializing the "instance" within a "class initialization" function (your `init` function, but perhaps named differently). I would also make any nested functions `static`, since they aren't accessed from outside the file, they should be only accessed through the allocated object.

Comment: Oh... and also your illegal function pointer conversions are completely undefined behavior and are very likely to result in program crashes on most systems out there. Sorry for spamming so many comments but you really should remake this whole code from scratch.

Comment: `(*func)()` is without argument because one of its arguments would be of the type of `STR_X2` which is not defined at that point. Do you know how should I add the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking `STR_X2` by value in `init` and `multiply` - this causes a copy. Take it by pointer instead to modify the `static` instance you declared in `main`.